# Intent.putExtra causes "skipped frames"

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to launch Activity A from Activity B. When I call

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
 intent.putExtra("date", date);
startActivity(intent);
```

I get "Skipped xx frames. The application may be doing to much work on its main thread". After comment intent.putExtra, everything is alright. What can be the reason that this one command makes error?

Comment: What exactly is date?

Comment: If date is a simple string or primitive, then I highly doubt your thread is struggling because of that.